# Post to api with parameters

Tags: c#, json, api

Trying to call an api :"https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/"
Is a post-call with this structure:

```
{
  "postcodes" : ["PR3 0SG", "M45 6GN", "EX165BL"]
}
```

What is the best practice to create the array of postcodes and how to send them?
My code:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
test.Add("OX49 5NU");
test.Add("M32 0JG");
test.Add("NE30 1DP");

var requestString = string.Join(",", test.ToArray());

var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "postcodes", requestString }
};

var s = queryParams.ToString();
var data = new StringContent(queryParams.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var uri = "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/";
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, data);
```

Not working.

Kind regards
/Rudy

Comment: "not working" is such a nebulous way to describe a problem, don't you think?

Comment: Anyway, you might want to take a look at what `queryParams.ToString()` actually yields. [Example](https://rextester.com/CLNN77793). You seem to want JSON, so you should look into using a JSON serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `.ToString()` at all and rely on the wonderful JSON serialization available in .Net.

```
    List<string> postcodes = new List<string>
    {
        "OX49 5NU",
        "M32 0JG",
        "NE30 1DP"
    };

    var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { postcodes });
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var uri = "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/";
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

`new { postcodes }` creates an anonymous type with a single property named `postcodes` consisting of the list of postcodes.

Note also the `using` on httpClient. For a trivial example it probably doesn't matter but you should at least be disposing of the httpClient properly.

**UPDATE**
As @marsze pointed out, it's usually best to use [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests), calling `CreateClient()` when you need a `HttpClient` this will allow .Net to pool HttpClients that can be reused without consuming additional resources. This is really beyond the scope of the question/answer.

Comment: +1 for using an anonymous object, didn't think of that, nice. Also, the actually best way to use `HttpClient` is to inject an `IHttpClientFactory` and call `CreateClient()` (and **not** dispose the client).

Comment: @marsze I did consider mentioning that but it's probably beyond the scope of this example.

Answer (score 1):

Your request has to be in JSON format. For that, you might want to write your own DTO, somewhat like this:

```
class PostcodeBody
{
    public List<string> Postcodes { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```

And then serialize it using the JSON serializer of your choice:

```
var body = new PostcodeBody();
body.Postcodes.Add("OX49 5NU");
body.Postcodes.Add("M32 0JG");
body.Postcodes.Add("NE30 1DP");
var data = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```